# How to determine level of scale build up

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance

I would like to find out if my machine already has enough scale-buildup for a descaling session.

It's a 2 group, heat exchange copper boiler. About 10,000 shots through the machine. I use filtered water from a water supplier.

Lastly, do you have any references of descaling procedures for machines like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see the inside of your machine (alternatively, the hardness of the water source, together with the exact temperature and volume of the water as well as time it stays in the boiler) you can only guess whether you need it or not.

I have o domestic type machine at home and I descale it after every 100 or 200 shots.

I'm pretty sure that your industrial boiler also needs descaling in these days. Even if you use filtered water, it is better to be sure.